# Using keyword arguments in function to make generation of n-grams optional

Tags: python, function, nlp, keyword-argument

Example of how my xml file looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="folia.xsl"?>
<FoLiA xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://ilk.uvt.nl/folia" xml:id="untitled" generator="libfolia-v0.10">
  <metadata type="native">
    <annotations>
      <token-annotation annotator="ucto" annotatortype="auto" datetime="2017-04-17T14:50:04" set="tokconfig-nl"/>
      <pos-annotation annotator="frog-mbpos-1.0" annotatortype="auto" datetime="2017-04-17T14:50:04" set="http://ilk.uvt.nl/folia/sets/frog-mbpos-cgn"/>
      <lemma-annotation annotator="frog-mblem-1.1" annotatortype="auto" datetime="2017-04-17T14:50:04" set="http://ilk.uvt.nl/folia/sets/frog-mblem-nl"/>
      <chunking-annotation annotator="frog-chunker-1.0" annotatortype="auto" datetime="2017-04-17T14:50:04" set="http://ilk.uvt.nl/folia/sets/frog-chunker-nl"/>
      <entity-annotation annotator="frog-mwu-1.0" annotatortype="auto" datetime="2017-04-17T14:50:04" set="http://ilk.uvt.nl/folia/sets/frog-mwu-nl"/>
      <entity-annotation annotator="frog-ner-1.0" annotatortype="auto" datetime="2017-04-17T14:50:04" set="http://ilk.uvt.nl/folia/sets/frog-ner-nl"/>
      <morphological-annotation annotator="frog-mbma-1.0" annotatortype="auto" datetime="2017-04-17T14:50:04" set="http://ilk.uvt.nl/folia/sets/frog-mbma-nl"/>
      <dependency-annotation annotator="frog-depparse-1.0" annotatortype="auto" set="http://ilk.uvt.nl/folia/sets/frog-depparse-nl"/>
    </annotations>
  </metadata>
  <text xml:id="untitled.text">
    <p xml:id="untitled.p.1">
      <s xml:id="untitled.p.1.s.1">
        <w xml:id="untitled.p.1.s.1.w.1" class="WORD">
          <t>De</t>
          <pos class="LID(bep,stan,rest)" confidence="0.999701" head="LID">
            <feat class="bep" subset="lwtype"/>
            <feat class="stan" subset="naamval"/>
            <feat class="rest" subset="npagr"/>
          </pos>
          <lemma class="de"/>
          <morphology>
            <morpheme>
              <t offset="0">de</t>
            </morpheme>
          </morphology>
        </w>
```

I'm making a function to generate word uni-, bi-and trigrams out of a xml-file. I want to make the n-gram optional, so that you can chose whether you want all n-grams or for example only unigrams. The outcome of my function is the vectorized relative frequency of the word n-gram. I tried this by using keyword arguments in my parameters (using True and False). I get an empty dictionary, so I must be doing something wrong. Here is what I have. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def word_ngrams(frogged_xmlfile, unigrams=True, bigrams=True, trigrams=True):
    vector = {}
    tree = ET.parse(frogged_xmlfile) #enter the xml tree
    root = tree.getroot()
    tokens = []
    words = []
    regex = re.compile(r'[^0-9] |[^(\.|\,|\?|\:|\;|\!)]')
        for node in root.iter('w'):
        for w in node.findall('t'):
            tokens.append(w.text)
    for word in tokens:
        if regex.search(word):
            words.append(word)
    if (unigrams):
        for n in [1]: #unigrams
            grams = ngrams(words, n)
            fdist = FreqDist(grams)
            total = sum(c for g,c in fdist.items())
        for gram, count in fdist.items():
            vector['w'+str(n)+'+'+' '.join(gram)] = count/total

    if (bigrams):
        for n in [2]: #bigrams
            grams = ngrams(tokens, n)
            fdist = FreqDist(grams)
            total = sum(c for g,c in fdist.items())
        for gram, count in fdist.items():
            vector['w'+str(n)+'+'+' '.join(gram)] = count/total

    if (trigrams):
        for n in [3]: #trigrams
            grams = ngrams(tokens, n)
            fdist = FreqDist(grams)
            total = sum(c for g,c in fdist.items())
        for gram, count in fdist.items():
            vector['w'+str(n)+'+'+' '.join(gram)] = count/total
    return vector
print(word_ngrams('romanfragment_frogged.xml', unigrams = True, bigrams = False, trigrams = False))
```

Comment: The unigram segment of this code needs to be indented, which will clear up your logic.

Comment: @robertlayton, the identation error was made when I typed the code in here. I fixed it, my problem remains. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @HughBothwell thank you for the edits, but that were also faults I made during typing the code in here

Comment: Would it be possible to get a short sample .xml file to parse? What exactly is "frogged" text - Google search is unhelpful?

Comment: @HughBothwell  yes, I just added a sample. Frog is a NLP tool for Dutch. So when I pass a text through Frog, it gets tokenized, parsed, tagged etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your search ignores the document default namespace, so it never finds matching tags.
2. Your regex is really awful -

   ```
   "[^0-9] "                   # not-a-digit, followed by space
   "|"                         # OR
   "[^(\.|\,|\?|\:|\;|\!)]"    # bad syntax, but I think you mean not one of .,?:;!
   ```

   It will accept any punctuation followed by a space (as not-a-digit), or any digit or other character or whitespace (as not-punctuation)! Basically the only thing it doesn't match is "a string consisting entirely of punctuation characters".

   I am going to guess that what you really wanted was "a string containing at least one letter and no non-letter characters", but feel free to correct me.
3. Your code does not include `ngrams()` or `FreqDist()` so I cannot test it.
4. The indentation of `for gram, count ...` looks incorrect - I think it should be indented one more level.
5. You have a lot of unnecessarily duplicated code.

Try this:

```
# import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

FOLIA_NAMESPACE = {
    'default': 'http://ilk.uvt.nl/folia',
    'xlink':   'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
}

def is_word(s):
    return s.isalpha()
    # as a regex:
    # return re.match("[A-Za-z]+$", s) is not None

def load_words(folia_xml_file, is_word=is_word, namespace=FOLIA_NAMESPACE):
    root = ET.parse(folia_xml_file).getroot()
    tokens = root.findall(".//default:w/default:t", namespace)
    return [t.text for t in tokens if is_word(t.text)]

def make_ngram_vectors(words, n_values=[1,2,3]):
    vectors = {}
    for n in n_values:
        grams = ngrams(words, n)
        fdist = FreqDist(grams)
        total = sum(count for gram,count in fdist.items())
        for gram,count in fdist.items():
            key = "w{}+{}".format(n, " ".join(gram))
            vectors[key] = count / total
    return vectors

def main():
    words = load_words("romanfragment_frogged.xml")
    vectors = make_ngram_vectors(words, [1])
    print(vectors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Edit:**
If you look in the `<FoLiA>` tag at the top of your xml file, you will see `xmlns=` (the link defining the document's default namespace, ie what tags are available) and `xmlns:xlink=` (an alternate XLink namespace, which defines tags like `xlink:href` and `xlink:show` - see https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xlink.asp ).

ElementTree likes to expand namespaces inline so your tags look like `{http://ilk.uvt.nl/folia}w`. Passing a namespace dict lets us use more readable formatting like `default:w` instead.

To get the same input/output formats as your original function, you can use a wrapper function like:

```
def word_ngrams(folia_xml_file, unigrams=True, bigrams=True, trigrams=True):
    # condense parameters into n_values
    n_values = []
    if unigrams:
        n_values.append(1)
    if bigrams:
        n_values.append(2)
    if trigrams:
        n_values.append(3)
    words = load_words(folia_xml_file)
    return make_ngram_vectors(words, n_values)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help! Indeed, I want all the words, but no digits and no punctuation. I'm pretty new in programming, so I don't fully understand your code. I have a few questions. 1.what does the folia namespace exactly, especially x-link? 2.This function needs to fit into a feature extraction system, so the vectors of word n-grams are 1 feature to train a classifier on. I suppose it is not possible to fit your 4 functions into 1 big function?

Comment: I can't thank you enough. It is all so much clearer now!

Comment: I have another problem. I'm trying to make a unit test for